# Map tiles below -80 degrees appear inverted in UTM projection

Tags: coordinate-system, mapping, land-cover, global-mapper

I have a set of global land cover tiles at 30m per pixel resolution (GlobeLand30 or GLC30). They are TIF files in UTM projection, however I need to do some work using Geographic projection. Here is what it looks like when I import the files into my GIS tool (Global Mapper v22):

[image: UTM files]

And here is what the Projection dialogue looks like when I click on it:

[image: UTM projection]

Here is what the Projection dialogue looks like when I click to select Geographic projection:

[image: Geographic projection]

And here is what the map looks like when I convert it to Geographic projection:

[image: Geographic files]

To my untrained eye, it appears as though the "bottom" part of the globe (i.e. anything below -80 degrees latitude) is loading "inverted". Here is a close up of Antarctica south of South America so that you can see what I mean:

[image: Antarctica zoom]

The original file set is definitely correct as can be seen from this screenshot from GLC30's online map viewer (from which these TIF files were downloaded):

[image: GLC30 map viewer]

Am I doing something wrong, or is there perhaps something wrong with the metadata in these TIF files causing them to load incorrectly? How do I get them to load so that the region of Antarctica approaching the South Pole looks correct?

Please let me know if you need any more information from me to solve this problem as I'm not a GIS expert and can only really tell you what steps I've taken and the problem as it appears to me.